# Fail message with opkg in yocto project

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, opkg

### I am not sure that this is the best place to ask about yocto, there is a webpage such a forum only of yocto? This is my first question. The second question is related to the title, I have problems with the opkg when I am trying install packets. I have tried to update and upgrade but when I update don't find packets. I adjunt a example with the message that I obtain when I execute the opkg command:

- root@sama5d27-wlsom1-ek-sd~# opkg install curl
  Collected errors:

- opkg_prepare_url_for_install: Couldn't find anything to satisfy 'curl'.

---

This message appears whith any package that I want install, I don't know what happenned, I need help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not appropriate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***For your first question:***

No, this is not the only place to ask about `Yocto`.

For more professional community visit Yocto mailing list in this [link](https://lists.yoctoproject.org/g/main).

***For your second question:***

In order to use `package manager` in Yocto (opkg, apt, dnf), you need to configure your package feeds to a source list server that the board will fetch the sources from.

In order to do that, Yocto offers a method that makes you able to start a server inside the Yocto generated packages, and based on that you configure the board's run-time package manager to fetch from that server.

For more detailed information, please check this [link](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/next/dev-manual/packages.html#using-runtime-package-management), and follow instructions and detailed documentation.